# In symmetric matrix if $A^6=I \implies A^2=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a 3×3 real symmetric matrix such that $A^6 =I.$Then, $A^2 = I.$

Please give me a hint !

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that you're going to need to show more work than that to get a positive response. What do you know about the properties of real symmetric matrices that might be applicable here? What about matrices that can be squared to produce the identity matrix, in particular?

Comment: Also, did you mean to write $A^6=I$ instead of $A^6=1$?

Comment: Sorry i mean $A^6=I$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists inverse matrix $P$ such that $$PAP^{-1}=diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3).$$
So $$PA^6P^{-1}=diag(\lambda_1^6,\lambda_2^6,\lambda_3^6)=I.$$
This implies $$\lambda_1^6=\lambda_2^6=\lambda_3^6=1.$$
So $$\lambda_1^2=\lambda_2^2=\lambda_3^2=1;$$
$$PA^2P^{-1}=diag(\lambda_1^2,\lambda_2^2,\lambda_3^2)=I;$$
and $$A^2=I.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$x^6-1=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$

Comment: Ia it possible to have polynomial of matrix?

Comment: Yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)

Comment: Thanks for your help